# Arabic title of Image from URL not displaying in UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

i have a simple question, Am trying to display an image from URL in`UIImageView`. When that image title on the URL is in arabic the image is not showing if that image is in english it showing in `UIImageView`. So how to convert arabic.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If understand correctly, you are having arabic characters in the URL. You need to percent escape these characters for it to work.

Use this,

```
NSURL *percentEscapedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[unescapedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: http://psyc.org.sa/ar/wp-content/uploads/اعداد-القادة-150x150.jpg   please see this link. i tried you code but not working.

Comment: @user2706827 If you hit that URL in the browser it gives 404. Those characters are not in the permitted range of characters.

Comment: you are right. i think there is a problem with url. now its working

Answer (score 0):

Use the encoding as NSUTF8StringEncoding, encode the path